# Missing '#include "m1.hpp"'; 'my_type' must be defined before it is used

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, c++20

There is a `m1.hpp` header file defining `my_type`. The header is included by `m2` module. The module exports `my_class` (has a member of `my_type`) used in `main`. How can I fix the compilation issue (see below) without including `m1.hpp` (that would defeat the purpose) in `main`? (I'm using clang from trunk).

```cpp
// file: m1.hpp
#pragma once
class my_type {};
```

```cpp
// file: m2.cppm
module;      
#include "m1.hpp"      
export module m2;      
export class my_class { my_type m; };
```

```cpp
// file: main.cpp
import m2;
int main() { my_class c; }
```

```
clang++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++2a -fprebuilt-module-path=. --precompile m2.cppm -o m2.pcm
clang++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++2a -fprebuilt-module-path=. -c m2.pcm -o m2.obj
clang++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++2a -fprebuilt-module-path=. -c main.cpp -o main.obj
```

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
m2.cppm:5:14: error: missing '#include "m1.hpp"'; 'my_type' must be defined before it is used
export class my_class { my_type m; };
             ^
main.cpp:3:23: note: in implicit default constructor for 'my_class' first required here
int main() { my_class c; }
                      ^
m1.hpp:3:7: note: previous definition is here
class my_type {};
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: The class definition should be in the hpp file which should be included in both cpp files.    You can't export a definition, only data.

Comment: @stark My question is about C++20. The `m2.cppm` is a "module interface unit", not a regular cpp file.

Comment: Try putting `module;` after the `#include`. I think I've had a similar problem

Comment: @HolyBlackCat With `module;` after the `#include` the error is different - "error: 'module;' introducing a global module fragment can appear only at the start of the translation unit".